# When button hold raise an event every 0.5 seconds

Tags: c#, button, windows-8, winrt-xaml, windows-8.1

I want to detect when you started a tap / click inside on a button inside a windows 8 app. In WPF I would use the OnMouseButtonDown event, the OnMouseButtonUp and a timer. But I'm not able to use those events.

Does anyone has a solution for this problem?

---

I've tried to use the XAML events, but for some reason they didn't seem to work. I tried it through code (by suggestion of a friend). When I did that, it did work.

The repeater button is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: Sure you can, these events just have different names.  It is not a "mouse" anymore when you poke at it with your pointy finger.

Comment: PointerDown/PointerUp?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the [RepeatButton](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.repeatbutton%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). You can set initial delay and interval.